# How to get public key of generated keypair?

Tags: web3.js

Shouldn't this work to get the public key according to the documentation? I tried the below code and get an error TypeError: wallet.publicKey is not a function.
https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Keypair.html

```
let wallet = solana_web3.Keypair.generate();
console.log(wallet.publicKey());
```

How do I get a copy of this https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/PublicKey.html from the generated wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe that you just need to replace `wallet.publicKey()` with `wallet.publicKey` because you are reading a property, not calling a method

Answer (score 1):

```
import { PublicKey, Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";

const wallet = Keypair.generate();
const pubKey=wallet.publicKey
```

as your [PublicKey docs](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/PublicKey.html) link, PublicKey is a class and its constructor is

```
new PublicKey(value: PublicKeyInitData): PublicKey
```

to create a `PublicKey` instance

```
// I generated the pubKey above
const publicKeyInstance = new PublicKey(pubKey);
```

Now you should be accessing all the methods in the PublicKey docs